# Sonar analysis run fails when java variables contains scandinavian letters

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am running Sonar analysis on my project. Some java variables contain scandinavian letters (bad practice, I know) and the Sonar analysis run breaks when it encounters this type of letter. Any ideas on what to do with this (other than remove the scandic letters)?

Comment: Have you tried converting the input to utf-8? That usually solves a legion of problems.

Comment: what input? how do I do that? do you mean including utf-8 encoding at the sonar target?

Comment: I assume it scans the source files. Safe the source files as UTF-8. Then run sonar again. That's the easiest solution I can think of. If it doesn't work well, I'd suggest opening all source files in notepad++ press CTRL + H and replace all offending characters with a "normal" one(don't forget to check replace in all files)

Comment: I checked the java source file and it is actually saved as UTF-8, according to Eclipse.

Comment: Then I'd suggest the notepad++ solution. Replace them all in one fell swoop with normal a-z charachters.

Comment: make sure, that the console encoding is UTF8, on Linux this is mostly defined by $LANG

Comment: Have you tried to use the sonar.sourceEncoding property ? http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters